# Access job's workspace in a docker container step in dockerized Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-docker

I have a dockerized jenkins server. In a freestyle job I have a bash step that I'd like to run in a docker container. While I'm able to create a docker from inside the Jenkins docker it's not trivial how to give access to the current job's workspace to the new container step. This is possible in the pipeline syntax by setting `reuseNode` boolean to True. What is the equivalent of this in a freestyle Jenkins job? I can pass something like `-v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home --workdir $WORKSPACE` to the new container and it almost works but I usually get all sorts of permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Docker agents? As far as I understand your usecase, it does exactly what you want and takes care of user and volume management. Check [this article](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) for directions.

Comment: yes, I'm looking for the equivalent when I don't have a pipeline. In my usecase I have a simple a freestyle project and I'm creating a container in a bash step.